# Build a completed Cordova app in XCode for deployment to TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, testflight

I have built an Cordova app that currently runs on both Android & iOS platforms, I have am trying to use Xcode to setup my app so that I am able to push this onto the TestFlight application for testing on multiple other devices.

The Cordova instructions don't really explain the process well in regards to exporting a completed app for testing on TestFlight & submitting to the store.

Can anyone provide any advice on how this works - basically I want to copy over my working app into Xcode so I am able to get the bundle ID I need to set this up in iTunes Connect

-- update --

I now have the app working on a real iPhone device - I had to setup the **Code Signing Identity** to our actual iOS developer account. Now the next step will be to push the app into the iTunes Connect to send this app to others for testing via 'Test Flight'

Comment: What have you done so far? Did you add the iOS platform via CLI?  https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html.

Comment: thanks - the iOS platform has been added, along with the ios-sim & ios-deploy CLI's commands. I didn't realise the xcode project file that Cordova automatically creates (I thought this had to be done manually so now my app is setup within the Xcode environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cordova platform generates an Xcode project file - double clicking this opens up the app in Xcode now.